# How do I create multiple polylines with separate on click functionality?

Tags: leaflet

I'm iterating an array of objects in my script which has polyline data. Then I add the iterated object to my map. The problem is, I can't assign different onclick events to iterated object since defining the variable is overriden by the last iteration

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.$store.state.streets.length; i++) {
var currentIteratedStreet = this.$store.state.streets[i]
var latlngs = currentIteratedStreet.latlngs
var polyline = L.corridor(latlngs, {
    color: '#0068ff',
    opacity: 0.5,
    corridor: 5,
    lineCap: 'square',
}).addTo(mymap)

polyline.on('click', () => {
    console.log(polyline.options)
})
}
```

`var polyline` is always overriden by the last iteration (which is expected) and prints the same output for each polyline. I couldn't find any source that renders me able to add separate onclick functions for each polyline. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a parameter to the function triggered by `click` to work on the event and retrieve the object that triggered it with `event.target` :

```
polyline.on('click', (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.options);
})
```